# Calculating document frequency in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How to calculate document frequency using SQL?

Document frequency is the number of documents (rows) in which a term appears, not the total count of a term (that's the term frequency).

I can calculate the term frequency like this:

```
create table countries (
  iso char(2) primary key,
  name text not null unique
);

insert into countries values 
('GS', 'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands'),
('ZA', 'South Africa');

select
  term
  , count(*) as term_frequency
from 
  countries
  , regexp_split_to_table(name, '[^\.\w]') term
where 
  term <> ''
group by
  term;
```

However I'm not quite sure how to get the document frequency (should be 2 for "South" not 3).

The output should look like this:

```
term     document_frequency
---------------------------
South    2
Georgia  1
and      1
the      1
Sandwich 1
Islands  1
Africa   1
```

Comment: Can you add a term the from to accept something like `(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM regexp_split_to_table(name, '[^\.\w]')) term`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So count the number of distinct documents per term:

```
select term, count(DISTINCT iso) as doc_frequency
from   countries
     , regexp_split_to_table(name, '[^\.\w]') term
where  term <> ''
group  by term;
```

Comment: Brain Fart cured! Thanks Erwin, you're always on point. I always forget about count(distinct)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

`select count(*) from countries where name similar to concat('\w', term, '\w');`

The above is untested and likely has a syntax error or 4, but I think the general idea should work.

Comment: [`SIMILAR TO` is just pointless.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql/10696#10696) Use `LIKE` or a regular expression match (`~`) instead. Also, this does not produce the desired result.